# How can I get only new emails from pop3 server into my application?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I'm developing email application that works on web browser.

I could get emails from pop3 server using Qd mail, Japanese PHP library but I have a problem.
When I want to get only new emails, I have to remove emails from pop3 server after save those into database table of my application.

General email applications like gmail, outlook and thunder bird etc. can get new emails without removing those emails.

How can I get emails without removing those like gmail, outlook and thunder bird?

```
Language: PHP
Library: Qd Mail
Mail sever :POP3 server
Application server: Xampp
```

This is the code.

```
<?php
  include_once(dirname(__FILE__, 3).'\qdmail_receiver.php');

  $servername = "localhost";
  $username = "username";
  $password = "password";

  $db_mail = "sekisan_mail";
  $tbl_email = "emails";
  $tbl_attach = "attached_file_received";
  
  // Create connection
  $db_connect_mail = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db_mail);
  
  // Check connection
  if ($db_connect_mail->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db_connect_mail->connect_error);
  } else {
    $db_connect_mail->set_charset("utf8");
  }

  $mailserver = array(
    'protocol'=>'pop3',
    'host'=>'host server',
    'user'=>'user',
    'pass'=>'pass',
    'port'=>110
  );

  $receiver = QdmailReceiver::start('pop', $mailserver);

  for($i = 1 ; $i <= $receiver->count() ; $i++){
    $from = $receiver->header(array('from','mail'));
    $subject = $receiver->header(array('subject','name'));
    $subject = addslashes($subject);
    $subject = htmlspecialchars($subject);
    $date = $receiver->header('date');
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Tokyo');
    $date = strtotime($date);
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i', $date);
    $bd = $receiver->bodyAutoSelect();
    $bd = addslashes($bd);
    $attached_files = $receiver->attach();
    $pointer = $receiver->pointer();
    $receiver->delete($pointer); // Here delete email.
    $receiver->next();
    $count_attach = count($attached_files);
    
    $sql = "
      insert into "
        .$tbl_email."(
          from_who,
          subject, 
          text, 
          status, 
          received_datetime
        )
      values (
        '$from',
        '$subject',
        '$bd',
        0,
        '$date'
      );";

    $query = $db_connect_mail->query($sql);

    if(!$query) {
      echo "
                <div class='message-wrapper error'>
                    <p><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> メールの取得に失敗しました。</p>
                    <p>エラー：".$db_connect_mail->error."</p>
                </div>";
    }

    $sql = "select id from ".$tbl_email." order by id desc limit 1;";

    $query = $db_connect_mail->query($sql);
    
    if(!$query) {
      echo "
                <div class='message-wrapper error'>
                    <p><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> データ取得エラー</p>
                    <p>エラー：".$db_connect_mail->error."</p>
                </div>";
    } else {
      $result_mail_id = $query->fetch_all();
      $mail_id = $result_mail_id[0][0];

      if ($count_attach > 0) {
        $received_file_path = "../../assets/attached_files/sekisan/received/".$mail_id;
  
        if (!file_exists($received_file_path)) {
          mkdir($received_file_path, 0777, true);
        }
  
        $sql = "insert into ".$tbl_attach."(mail_id, file_name, error) values ";
  
        for($i = 0; $i < $count_attach; $i++){
          $attached_file = $attached_files[$i];
  
          // ファイル名の不要な部分を削除。この時点ではname="ファイル名"という状態で受け取っている。
          $filename = $attached_file["filename"];
          $filename = str_replace('"', '', $filename);
          $filename_safe = "tmp_file";
          $file_value = $attached_file['value'];
  
          // ファイルを一時的にtmp_fileとして保存。
          $file = fopen($received_file_path."/".$filename_safe, 'w');
          fputs($file, $file_value);
          fclose($file);
  
          // ファイル名をtmp_fileからもともとのファイル名に変更。
          // rename(FILE_DIR."/".$filename_safe, FILE_DIR."/".$filename);
          if (!rename($received_file_path."/".$filename_safe, $received_file_path."/".$filename)) {
            if ($i == 0) {
              $sql = $sql."('".$mail_id."', '".$filename."', '1')";
            } else {
              $sql = $sql.", ('".$mail_id."', '".$filename."', '1')";
            }
          } else {
            if ($i == 0) {
              $sql = $sql."('".$mail_id."', '".$filename."', '0')";
            } else {
              $sql = $sql.", ('".$mail_id."', '".$filename."', '0')";
            }
          }
        }
  
        $sql = $sql.";";
  
        $query = $db_connect_mail->query($sql);
      
        if(!$query) {
          echo "
                        <div class='message-wrapper error'>
                            <p><i class='fas fa-exclamation-circle'></i> 添付ファイルの取得に失敗しました。</p>
                            <p>エラー：".$db_connect_mail->error."</p>
                        </div>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
  $receiver->done();

  $db_connect_mail->close();
?>
```

Comment: Why do you have to remove them? What does your code look like?

Comment: @GregSchmidt Because the app also gets read emails every time. I added my code. Check it.

Comment: I can't find any documentation on this QD Mail, so can't say what you might be doing wrong with it. There's nothing obviously wrong in your code; if such an option exists, it's probably some other parameter that needs to be passed to their functions. Do you have to use POP3, or would IMAP work?